# Would adding a '&' in the URL referring to an anchor tag on a different page break it?

Tags: html, anchor

ex. using /faq/#test&lt one one page to refer to anchor tag id="test&lt" on another page.

I didn't create this code, but in trying to fix it I'm trying to understand why it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The & is a special character used in HTML to display chars with a special meaning; chars that can't by written directly. For example &lt is "<" and &gt is ">".

I'd say it's highly recommended to avoid using this chars in object ids such as in your example, even if I tried and it's working (in Chrome). I wouldn't use them anyway, maybe some browsers or web servers are even blocking such requests.

I would use some more usual id, as "test1", "test2",...

Try it yourself, it's working anyway even with &lt.

First file (doc1.html):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="doc2.html#test">test</a>
        <br />
        <a href="doc2.html#test&lt">test&lt</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second file (doc2.html):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a id="test">doc2</a>
        test
        <p style="height:1500px" >&nbsp;</p>
        <a id="test&lt">doc2</a>
        test&lt
    </body>
</html>
```